# No module named 'quantlib' in VS Code M1 Mac

Tags: python

Im trying to install `QuantLib` package.

I used `brew install quantlib` in terminal and it succeed.

And I tried `import quantlib as ql` in VScode but there's No module named `quantlib` error message came out.

Also I tried `import QuantLib as ql` as well.

I don't know how to solve this problem. I tried `pip install QuantLib` and it didn't work at all in my terminal.

I use M1 MacBook Pro.

Thank you

Comment: Choose proper python interpreter https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment

Comment: Does `pip install QuantLib` still not work as of now?  In theory the last couple of releases were built with universal support, but I don't have a M1 machine to test them.

Comment: @LuigiBallabio No, I'm working with an M1 I'm still getting ```ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement QuantLib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for QuantLib```

Comment: If you're using the default Python that came with your Mac, you might try installing the supposedly universal version available at <https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3104/>.  Otherwise, you'll have to compile the QuantLib module yourself (see <https://www.quantlib.org/install.shtml>) until I can get access to a M1 machine to produce the wheels.

Answer (score -1):

if this doesn't work
`pip install QuantLib`

try to add this package in **pycharm**

Most of times i also do like this to avvoid these errors.
hope it works for you too..:)

Comment: This donesn't work either.. but thank you